# jQuery get max width of child div's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the max width(just the one width) of the child div in the wrapper div element

```
<div id="wrapper">  
    <div class="image"><img src="images/1.jpg"></div> 
    <div class="image"><img src="images/2.jpg"></div>  
    <div class="image"><img src="images/3.jpg"></div>  
    <div class="image"><img src="images/4.jpg"></div>  
    <div class="image"><img src="images/5.jpg"></div>  
    <div class="image"><img src="images/6.jpg"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I imagine you've tried many things and are just omitting including your failed attempts in the question?

Comment: Very helpful Jared. If all you can do is get smart then don't bother leaving comments.

Comment: See my answer. This is not a very difficult problem. You state the "question" as a request of "someone write this for me." This isn't http://dice.com/. Give it a shot, see what happens. You might be surprised if you figure it out. :)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
Math.max.apply(Math, $('.image').map(function(){ return $(this).width(); }).get());
```

Per suggestion, I'll break that down:

```
$('.image').map(function(){
   return $(this).width();
}).get();
```

The above gets a list of all `.image` divs and converts it into a list of their widths.  So you'll now have something like: `[200, 300, 250, 100, 400]`.  The `.get()`, as Felix pointed out, is necessary to get an actual Array instead of a jQuery array.

`Math.max` takes N arguments, so you have to call it as: `Math.max(200, 300, 250, 100, 400)`, which is what the `Math.max.apply` piece accomplishes.

Comment: It doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/Shawn/6yfjb/
I know, the problem is me, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Shawn - "Math.max.apply( ___Math___, ..." --  you're currently calling `Math.max` with your array as `this` and no arguments.

Answer (score 9):

A not-so-difficult example function to consider; not as elegant as cwolves, but probably easier to follow if you're a beginner.

```
function getMaxChildWidth(sel) {
    max = 0;
    $(sel).children().each(function(){
        c_width = parseInt($(this).width());
        if (c_width > max) {
            max = c_width;
        }
    });
    return max;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/rMSuJ/1/

Comment: You crack me with beecker on js fiddle. I am new at jQuery so Im learning little by little. Thankyou

Comment: Don't be afraid to game plan what it is you're trying to do - this is exercise. After a while, you just come to see how you should approach these types of problems. But you have to try it yourself.

Answer (score 7):

I like this approach because it hits the sweet spot (IMHO) between core readability and shortness:

```
var max_w = 0;
$('#wrapper div.image').each(function() {
    max_w = Math.max(max_w, parseInt($(this).width()));
})
```

YMMV of course.

Comment: It is useful to use:  `.css('min-width', max_w)`