# how to get max-width available for a div by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 divs like

```
<div id="d1" style="float:left;width:150px;">
asdqwe
</div>
<div id="d2" style="float:left;">
qwerty
</div>
<div id="d3" style="float:right;width:150px;">
poilkj
</div>
```

Now i want to set d2 div width dynamically and set it maximum available with as per screen resolution by using jquery.

I tried `jQuery('#d2').width()` but it gives us only actually hold width.

I want to show up my webpage screen like d1 for 150px from left and d3 for 150px from right and rest of available widht for d2.

Please let me know how do we do it????

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `<div>` only fills the space it needs when floated.

You can't *get* the width you require like this, but you can *set* it:

```
$("#d2").width($(window).width() - $("#d1").width() - $("#d1").width);
```

Be warned: if the user resizes their window (or anything else to change the viewport size), you will need to update this value. You might want to get around this by hooking onto the window resize event:

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    $("#d2").width($(window).width() - $("#d1").width() - $("#d1").width);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
entireScreenWidth = screen.width
d1Width = $("#d1").width()
d2Width = $("#d2").width()

$("#d3").width(entireScreenWidth-d1Width-d2Width)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, you need to get screen width and deduct width of #d1 and #d3 from screen width. This calculated width can be assigned to #d2.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the viewport width using

```
var screenWidth = $( window ).width();
```

Then set the width for `#d2` as :

```
$('#d2').css('width', screenWidth - 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.max.apply(Math, $('#d2').map(function(){ return $(this).width(); }).get());
```

Per suggestion, I'll break that down:

```
$('#d2').map(function(){
   return $(this).width();
}).get();
```

Math.max takes N arguments, so you have to call it as: Math.max(200, 300, 250, 100, 400), which is what the Math.max.apply piece accomplishes.

Comment: Follow this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784388/jquery-get-max-width-of-child-divs

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
setMaxWidth();
$( window ).bind( "resize", setMaxWidth ); //Remove this if it's not needed. It will react when window changes size.

function setMaxWidth() {
$( "#d2" ).css( "maxWidth", ( $( window ).width() * 0.7 | 0 ) + "px" );
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't float the middle div, and put the floating ones before it in the source, you won't need any Javascript, because the browser can handle this by itself.

```html
<div id="d1" style="float:left;width:150px;">
asdqwe
</div>
<div id="d3" style="float:right;width:150px;">
poilkj
</div>
<div id="d2">
qwerty
</div>
```

Unless you have requirements that you haven't told us about, this should do it.

Comment: But in this case, `d2` will fill all the available space - not just the space remaining after inserting the floated divs, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/xMPsS/1/

Comment: Being able to give the divs different background colors could be one of those requirements that the OP didn't tell us. Anyway, you can solve this by giving ALL the divs explicit background colours: http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/xMPsS/2/

Comment: Sorry the background was just to demonstrate. The requirement was *I want to show up my webpage screen like d1 for 150px from left and d3 for 150px from right and **rest of available widht for d2***. But hey, who knows - it's not very clear :)

Comment: Indeed. Depending on what the OP actually NEEDS, my answer may or may not be the solution. And I'm pretty sure that, whatever the requirements,  there is a solution that doesn't require JS.