# Finding longest li and setting each li to that length

Tags: jquery, css

I have a drop down with button's inside it for a touchscreen application. My li's are inline because I am turning them into buttons. I can no0t have them display block or inline-block. They have to be inline. So it's pretty much set up like this...

```
<ul>
    <!-- ko foreach: Options -->
        <li role="presentation" class='item'><a class='btn btn-primary dropdownBtn' role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-bind="html: Name">&nbsp;</a></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

And this works fine with the items showing up, however each of them have their own width and it looks odd and mismatched in the list. So what I have been trying to do is finding the longest li and then set the rest of them to that length so they will all be even.

I cannot go the easy route here and set a min or max width because these are dynamic lists and I have no idea what will be generated in them.

So far, I have been trying something like this.

```
//This grabs each li based on the dropdown that is clicked on.
var lis = $(event.currentTarget).next().find('li');
```

and then I was trying to loop through each of them within that list and find the width

```
var maxWidth = 0;
var elemWidth = 0;
    $(lis).each(function() {
        elemWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
        if (parseInt($(this).css('width')) > maxWidth) {
            maxWidth = elemWidth;
        }
    });
```

But the width keeps returning 0 even though there is obviously a width attached to it or else it would not be showing or be showing up weird. I am able to get the value within the console, but no matter what I try here it keeps returning that 0.

I have tried getting the outerWidth or just the width(), but they both eaither return 0 or cause an error saying there can't be a function there. This is where I think my main problem is.

And then I would set the li's at the right width.

```
$(lis).each(function() {
    $(this).css('width', maxWidth + "px");
});
```

Any help would be awesome! I'm offically stuck!

Comment: Shouldn't `lis` be all of the list items within `<ul>`? I.e `var lis = $('ul li');`? http://jsfiddle.net/vmm19gw3/1/

Comment: @George The current target is doing that. It's targeting the ul that is clicked on and then the li's within it. So it's making sure that it's only grabbing the right dropdown.

Comment: Target the anchor tag and not the list item tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the max width of the li using Math.max:

```
var maxW = Math.max.apply(Math, $('li').map(function(){ return $(this).width(); }).get());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ur3ctabo/)

and set the width for all li with `$("li").width(maxW);`

[Fiddle - get and set max width](http://jsfiddle.net/ur3ctabo/1/)

And as reference: [jQuery get max width of child div's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784388/jquery-get-max-width-of-child-divs)

Comment: I'm not trying to get the max width though, I'm just trying to get the width of the longest li.

Comment: @zazvorniki Sorry for possible misunderstanding, but isn't the width of the longest li the max width of all li elements?

Answer (score -1):

After your comment, I changed my CSS-only answer to a jQuery solution. I used the same list as before and tried to keep it minimal. The code iterates over the list items, gets the width of the longest one, and applies the width to all of them.

Things to take into account: I think the items need to be at least inline-block to be able to get and set the width correctly. When applying the CSS, I think you need to add 'px' as well to make it legal. The `$.width()` function calculates the width, which is better than getting the width css attribute. If you get the CSS, you get the width from the stylesheet. Since you didn't add any, this won't be the value you need.

```js
$(function(){
  var maxWidth = 0;
  var $items = $('li.item');
  $items.each(function(){
      var width = $(this).width();
      if (width > maxWidth)
        maxWidth = width;
    });
  $items.css('width', maxWidth + 'px');
});
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li role="presentation" class='item'>Short</li>
  <li role="presentation" class='item'>Less short</li>
  <li role="presentation" class='item'>Even lesser short</li>
  <li role="presentation" class='item'>Quite long</li>
  <li role="presentation" class='item'>This might very well be the longest one</li>
  <li role="presentation" class='item'>This one is not that long</li>
  <li role="presentation" class='item'>Quite avarage, atually</li>
  <li role="presentation" class='item'>Last but not least</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The li's have to be sitting next to each other. I really need them to be inline. That is why I am trying to do it this way. This really has to be accomplished with jQuery.

Comment: I added a jQuery solution. The problem was in the way you got the width of an element. Use `$(item).width()` instead.

Comment: For some reason, I can't get this to work. No matter what I'm setting $items to it's saying that it is undefined. I had to take it out of the function is it because it is no longer inside that function?

Answer (score -2):

How about setting `li` style to `display: block` ? I may be wrong, but I believe that it will make all of the `li`s to take 100% of the container's width.

### EDIT

I'm not really sure why this:

```
$('ul li').css('style', width + 'px !important');
```

doesn't work and this does:

```
$('ul li').attr('style', 'width:' + width + 'px !important');
```

But it seems to be the issue. Seems kinda' strange to me.

See here: http://jsbin.com/weduwuhizadu/1/

Entire code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // find the longest
  var width = 0;
  $('ul li').each(function() {
    var w = $(this).width();
    if(w > width) {
      width = w;
    }
  });


// assigning the 'width' to all:
  $('ul li').attr('style', 'width:' + width + 'px !important');
});
```

Comment: I can't, they have to be sitting next to each other. I don't want them fitting the entire container, I just want them to be all the same with may it be 65px or 100px.

Comment: Can you post your CSS then?

Comment: I am trying to do this with jQuery though, my css is not really relevant here. I'm trying to calculate the width of the longest and then set them all to that width.

Comment: That is just setting each li to style="width:0px !important"

Comment: @zazvorniki Well, maybe you're trying to set the width before the list is actually populated by your foreach loop?