# Rotated text container auto height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some 90 degree rotated spans in a container, and I would like to make the container's height set to be the height of the heighest rotated element.

First step is to get the heighest element's height:

```
var $max_width = Math.max.apply(Math, $('.tbl-value').map(function(){ 
  return $(this).width(); 
}).get());
```

Source: [jQuery get max width of child div's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784388/jquery-get-max-width-of-child-divs)

This solution looks correct for me but doesnt seem to be working somehow. The next step would be to set the parent container's height to the `$max_width` size.

Here's my code on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m4z5701p/

How could I manage to do this?

*Ps.: I know my JS code is messy, sorry for that.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.rotated-text {
     display: inline-block;
     overflow: hidden;

     width: 1.5em;
     line-height: 1.5;
 }
.rotated-text__inner {
     display: inline-block;
     white-space: nowrap;

     transform: translate(0,100%) rotate(-90deg);
     transform-origin: 0 0;
 }
.rotated-text__inner:after {
     content: "";
     float: left;
     margin-top: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<span class="rotated-text">
     <span class="rotated-text__inner">
         Rotated foo
     </span>
 </span>
```

The best article for the Rotation Solution try this i may works for you
http://kizu.ru/en/fun/rotated-text/

Comment: Thank you! +1 for the explanative article you linked. Works like charm, learned a lot!