# Bootstrap4 make all input-group-addons same width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to make all prepend add-ons same width?

i.e in this screenshot I would like Email, License Key 1 & License Key 2 to be the same length, is that possible.

If I did not use add-ons and just used regular labels and a form grid it would be possible but it seems to be the prepend addons look much nicer then regular labels.

[image]

Relevant Html is

```
<main class="container-fluid">
  <form action="/license.process" name="process" id="process" method="post">
      <div class="input-group mb-2">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <label class="input-group-text" id="licenseEmaillabel">
                  Email
              </label>
          </div>
          <input type="text" name="licenseEmail" value="paultaylor@jthink.net" class="form-control" aria-describedby="licenseEmaillabel">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group mb-2">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <label class="input-group-text" id="licenseKey1label">
                  License Key 1
              </label>
          </div>
          <input type="text" name="licenseKey1" value="51302c021440d595c860233f136731865a12cfad2ce2cc2" class="form-control" aria-describedby="licenseKey1label">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group mb-2">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <label class="input-group-text" id="licenseKey2label">
                  License Key 2
              </label>
          </div>
          <input type="text" name="licenseKey2" value="1e50214376557ba3e1dede6c490f33d07b738515c8c2a03" class="form-control" aria-describedby="licenseKey2label">
      </div>
      <h3 class="error" style="visibility:hidden;">
          &nbsp;
      </h3>
      <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
      <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
      <button onclick="j2html.tags.UnescapedText@d352d4f" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
          Get License
      </button>
  </form>
</main>
```

Comment: they are horizontally aligned. Did you mean the widths of the labels to be the same width?

Comment: If you only have the 3 fields and you know the text wont ever change just hard code the value of `.input-group-text {min-width: 150px; }` to your longest piece of text?

Comment: @soulshined yes imean the width of the labels, hardcoding width not good ideabecause change depending on language

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So this is actually pretty complicated, because each label is in it's own div and not part of a sibling chain. And afaik, Bootstrap does not support this type of sizing, only relative sizing form classes (which essentially only makes the font bigger). That kind of eliminates most possibilities that I can think of using flex/child properties. However, I think hard-coding is not the right word usage in this circumstance. But the idea is the same.

The example of using `min-width` is not right in this circumstance because `min-width` !== `width=xx`. For example, if you set `min-width` to 50px, but 1 string of text is longer than that, you still have the same problem as above. Essentially, if you don't want to set them **all** to one specific value, then your only other option is to use Javascript.

Here is my pure CSS workaround:

```
.input-group-prepend {
  width : 35%; /*adjust as needed*/
}

.input-group-prepend label {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

Additionally you could use Boostrap specific [inline styling](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/sizing/) classes, but that's arbitrary and one of the issues with Bootstrap (too many inline classes clutter code, and then you would have to manually add it to each element). Just offering it as an alternative

For example:

```
<div class="input-group-prepend w-50"> /* grows to 50% of parent*/
  <label class="input-group-text w-100" id="licenseEmaillabel"> /* grows to 100% of parent */
```

Comment: Thanks, the trouble with using percentages is that the width is only correct when the browser window is the right size, make the window smaller and the width becomes too small even though there is enough space to fit label and value. Min-Width would work for English (70% of userbase) if I set to right value, and would not look too bad for languages that require longer length because would still ensure all text was visible just not lined up. In fact  pages are created dynamically so I could set language specific widths, however quite alot of work for the reward.

Comment: But Im not trying to create a new groundbreaking design just to use Bootstrap as intended to create more polished version of my webapp. So am i simply wrong to be using addons like this, should I just be using a regular form label (i.e text above the input which isn't actually attached to the input field) ?

Comment: Its actually quite common to want to override bootstrap defaults, and justified IMO. However, they make it pretty annoying to do. If you don't want percentages, you could use a mix of both, default width of 25%, min-width of 150px and max-width of 250px for example. Or javascript of course, but then you'll have to worry about resizing windows with javascript solution. If you don't want bootstrap specific classes, then your issue will still be pretty similar because the labels are not apart of the same hierarchy. Someone may have a better solution than me, but it sounds like you need javascript

Comment: Sure, but what I would appreciate is knowing do you think I should be using input-group-prepend as labels like this or should I just not use input-group-prepend and just use the examples in the Forms components section of the Bootstrap4 documentation instead ?

Comment: Like you said, you like the way it looks compared to the normal labels. That's a subjective opinion, and ultimately its your project and you should do what you enjoy. But if the question is, am I using the class wrong? Then no, your not. Bootstrap4 does not discourage this behavior, and uses it the same way you are. So it's not taboo, or 'bad practice' to do it that way. Perfectly acceptable, just not easily customizable since they are not children of the same parent @PaulTaylor

Comment: I think they look better as well, but keep in mind, just because your using bootstrap fundamentally, does not mean you HAVE to use bootstrap fro everything. In other words, you could make your own custom input and just put in a bootstrap container

Comment: Okay thanks for that answer,maybe I will use it sometimes since there doesnt seem to be a way to do this for checkboxes, the examples show the checkbox as the addon rather than the label

Comment: The thing is I am an experienced devloper, but not an experienced webdeveloper so I don't want to make things unneccessarily hard for myself.

Comment: @PaulTaylor There are plenty of examples of them using text like [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#multiple-inputs) so don't worry, your on the right track. And im not passing judgment. Bootstrap really is annoying to customize for any developer, but that's why they let you download it in segments, or only the parts you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171610/discussion-between-soulshined-and-paul-taylor).

Answer (score 10):

Just using the bootstrap classes:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend col-3">
        <span class="input-group-text col-12">Name:</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend col-3">
        <span class="input-group-text col-12">Address 1:</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Street Address">
</div>
```

Looks like this:
[image: Prepends all the same width]

Answer (score 3):

Using jquery you could do something like this:

```
var biggest = Math.max.apply(Math, $('.input-group-text').map(function(){ return $(this).width(); }).get());
$('.input-group-text').width(biggest);
```

Math.max.apply reads all .input-group-text widths and returns the biggest one. The next line applies this width to all .input-group-text divs.

Sources:
[jquery-get-max-width-of-child-divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784388/jquery-get-max-width-of-child-divs)

Comment: I beleave it answers the question. As another approach I'd use a HTML table, s.t. the browser does the job for you with no any code.

Answer (score 3):

add `w-50` class to `input-group-prepend` and
add `w-100` class to `input-group-text`

like this

```
<div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group-prepend w-50">
     <span class="input-group-text w-100">label</span>
   </div>
   <input type="text" class="form-control " />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="col-md input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend col-5 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 px-0">
         <span class="input-group-text w-100">Label textx</span>
      </div>
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
   </div>
</div>
```

This will work! Adjust the col grids accordingly for `.input-group-prepend`!